# Simple Laravel project throws undefined variable error

Tags: laravel, view, controller

I have just started a project in Laravel and I try to show users in index view, but 'undefined variable' error appears.I have spent hours with no success, if you know something more please help.

I have posted my code below.

View

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
  <h2>Index Page</h2>

 @foreach($users as $user)
     {{$user->name}}
 @endforeach

@endsection
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $users = User::all();

        return view('home.index', [ 'users' => App\User::all() ]);
    }

}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('home/index');
});

Route::get('home.index', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Remove this route `Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('home/index');
});` and modify the other one like this `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ now shows error that User.php class not found but it is there

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: What about if you change the return on your controller to `return view('home.index', [ 'users' => $users ]);` ?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ same error user class not found

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` as @kidA commented? Do you have a User model under App namespace?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ yes i did that

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I found the problem, but since i cannot answer my own question i will delete it.

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question. Just scroll down and add the answer